# MongoDB Parse Error: URI does not have hostname, domain name and tld when connecting with localhost

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to connect mongoDB locally. But for some reason it throws this error.

**'MongoParseError: URI does not have hostname, domain name and tld'**

Here is my code:

```js
const DB = `mongodb://localhost/db_name`;
mongoose
  .connect(DB, {useNewUrlParser: true})
  .then(() => console.log('DB CONNECTION SUCCESSFUL!'))
  .catch(e => console.log('FAILED DB CONNECTION'));
```

I also tried replacing db string with this.:
`mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db_name`, but this also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

My `server.js` is below and it works.

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Collection = require('./models/collection')
const app = express()

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db_name', {
    useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true
})

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended:false }))

app.get('/', async (req,res) => {
    const docs = await Collection.find()
    res.render('index', { list : docs  })
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

Comment: I am unable to understand, I am doing exactly same thing for some reason it throws me that error.